# Improper integral of p and f

Tags: integration, polynomials, improper-integrals

Let $f,p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $p$ a polynomial. If $$\int_0^\infty fp \, dx = 0$$ 
Show that $f$ does not necessairly have to be the constant null function.

Comment: But of course? $p$ could be constant null.

Comment: Just take any nonzero function whose integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is $0$ and divide it by $p.$ For example, you could have $pf=1$ on this interval $(0,1)$ and $pf=-1$ on the interval $(1,2). \qquad$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг : That's an unnecessarily strong condition to impose on $p.$ Besides, the statement probably means "for every polynomial function $p$, there is a nonzero function $f$ such that" etc.

Comment: @MichaelHardy As stated, I thought what I said would be the easy way out. Once the question is edited, if it is not correct as stated, we will be able to make better statements, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
\int_0^1p(x)\,dx = a_1\ne0\\
\int_1^2p(x)\,dx = a_2\ne0
$$
Then
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}1/a_1 & \text{if } x\in[0,1]\\
       -1/a_2 & \text{if } x \in (1,2] \\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
will always give
$$
\int_0^\infty p(x)f(x)\,dx=0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

May be a bit of overkill but I want to supplement the other (+1) answer with a generic method for finding a $C^\infty$ example of $f$ to a given polynomial $p$. Furthermore, $f$ will vanish only at finitely many isolated points.

Consider the sequence of [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) $L_n(x)$, $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.  Possibly the quickest of defining them is the formula
$$L_n(x)=e^x \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x}x^n).$$
From that we see that $\deg L_n(x)=n$ for all $n$.
Their key property is their orthogonality:
$$
\int_0^\infty L_n(x)L_m(x)e^{-x}\,dx=0
$$
whenever $n\neq m$. Indeed, a slower method for constructing the sequence $(L_n(x))$ would be to apply the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization method to the sequence of monomials $1,x,x^2,\ldots$ with the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)e^{-x}\,dx$. And then add some normalization to make the coefficients look nice.

So to answer your question we can use
$$
f(x)=e^{-x}L_n(x)
$$
as long as $n>m=\deg p(x)$. This works because, by orthogonality, the polynomials $L_0,L_1,\ldots,L_m$ span the space of all polynomials of degree $\le m$. Therefore $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^mc_iL_i(x)$ for some coefficients $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_m$.